Unpivot/merging column values with a summarization in pandas df
I have a df that looks similar to this right now:

What I would like to do is to group by Name, Number and Year, summarize Amount, and then create a single new column that has all Countries based on that grouping, or a new column for each country (the number of which would have to be dynamic as the number of countries differs for each Name in the dataset). So the final df would look like one of the below:

or


This can be done pretty easily using groupby and aggregating as a list. For example:
df.groupby(['Name', 'Number', 'Year', 'Amount'], as_index=False)['Country'].agg(list)
this code would return the countries as a list
